# How can I reference an object drawn using the Graphics Class in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm fairly new to VB.NET.

I'm making a program where I have to draw shapes using the e.Graphics Class, and not using PowerPacks. I have been looking for a way to reference the created Object, to modify them, or to use their values. I was wondering if anyone could help me on this.

For Example:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black,20,40, 60, 40)
```

I want to do something like this:

```
dim temp as ::Something::
temp = e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black,20,40, 60, 40)

e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, temp.X2, temp.Y1, temp.X2+ 45, temp.Y1)
```

Where `X2` is the x coordinate of the end of the line drawn by variable temp, and so on.

The closest thing I found was by creating an array of Graphics Objects, but the DrawLine Method doesn't return a value, so I cannot not add it to the array.

This is my first question in stackOverflow, so I apologize if something wasn't clear. I will try my best to be responsive in the comments.

Thank you.

EDIT:
I'm trying to draw this.
https://s32.postimg.org/flk3b5e0l/Untitled.png

The above picture was done using PowerPacks, but since not all computers have PowerPacks, I'm trying to use the Graphics Class.

I think that using the value of a shape will make it easier to align another shape, which is why I'm looking for a way to reference the drawn shapes.

Comment: You are just drawing lines and such using `e.Graphics`.  It is not an `Object` at all, but pixels that need to be redrawn now and then.  You could have a `Rectangle` for example stores the coordinates to draw and check if the mouse is inside it,  Not sure if that is what you are after.

Comment: Similar question asked a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38707095/gdi-graphics-manipluation-after-it-is-created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Object` since you're just drawing, but you can use points or create your own structure which contains the coordinates of the lines you're drawing

Using the Point structure:

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        Dim p1 As New Point(20, 40)
        Dim p2 As New Point(60, 40)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, p1.X, p1.Y, p2.X, p2.Y)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, p2.X, p1.Y, p2.X + 45, p1.Y)
End Sub
```

Using a custom structure:

```
Public Structure lineCoords
    Public x1 As Integer
    Public x2 As Integer
    Public y1 As Integer
    Public y2 As Integer
End Structure

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        Dim _lineCoords1 As New lineCoords
        With _lineCoords1
            .x1 = 20
            .y1 = 40
            .x2 = 60
            .y2 = 40
        End With

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, _lineCoords1.x1, _lineCoords1.y1, _lineCoords1.x2, _lineCoords1.y2)

        Dim _lineCoords2 As New lineCoords
        With _lineCoords2
            .x1 = _lineCoords1.x2
            .y1 = _lineCoords1.y1
            .x2 = _lineCoords1.x2 + 45
            .y2 = _lineCoords1.y1
        End With

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, _lineCoords2.x1, _lineCoords2.y1, _lineCoords2.x2, _lineCoords2.y2)

End Sub
```